# Unable to play audio: Loading library gstreamer-lite from resource failed

Tags: java, javafx

When the JavaFX program launches, I'm attempting to play an audio file using the code structure:

```
private void playSound() {
    try {
        Media media = new Media(
                getClass()
                        .getResource("/audio/maze-sound.wav")
                        .toExternalForm()
        );
        this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        this.mediaPlayer.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Unexpectedly, I am receiving the following exception, which shouldn't be happening given that I added the media dependency and that it should have all other dependencies as well.

```
Loading library gstreamer-lite from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\gc\.openjfx\cache\21+31\amd64\gstreamer-lite.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\gc\.openjfx\cache\21+31\amd64\gstreamer-lite.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2418)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:852)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2021)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:140)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:56)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:115)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:108)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:78)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:90)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:240)
    at javafx.media@21/javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:392)
    at com.algorithms.maze/com.algorithms.maze.App.playSound(App.java:34)
    at com.algorithms.maze/com.algorithms.maze.App.start(App.java:26)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gstreamer-lite in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\gc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\gc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2458)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:916)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2059)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:168)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:56)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:115)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:108)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:78)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:90)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
    at javafx.media@21/com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:240)
    at javafx.media@21/javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:392)
    at com.algorithms.maze/com.algorithms.maze.App.playSound(App.java:34)
    at com.algorithms.maze/com.algorithms.maze.App.start(App.java:26)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.algorithms.maze.App
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Project structure:

```
C:.
|   .gitignore
|   mvnw
|   mvnw.cmd
|   pom.xml
|
+---.idea
|       .gitignore
|       compiler.xml
|       encodings.xml
|       jarRepositories.xml
|       misc.xml
|       uiDesigner.xml
|       vcs.xml
|       workspace.xml
|
+---.mvn
|   \---wrapper
|           maven-wrapper.jar
|           maven-wrapper.properties
|
\---src
    \---main
        +---java
        |   |   module-info.java
        |   |
        |   \---com
        |       \---algorithms
        |           \---maze
        |                   App.java
        |                   Cell.java
        |                   MazeController.java
        |                   MazeModel.java
        |                   MazeView.java
        |
        \---resources
            |   1322301.png
            |
            \---audio
                    maze-sound.wav
```

Comment: Github: https://github.com/gchapidze/maze-gen

Comment: Does `C:\Users\gc\.openjfx\cache\21+31\amd64\gstreamer-lite.dll` exist? How are you executing the project? What happens if you upgrade to JavaFX 21.0.1?

Comment: @Slaw Yes, ´C:\Users\gc\.openjfx\cache\21+31\amd64\gstreamer-lite.dll´ exists. I have an AMD CPU. I am executing project from Intellij IDEA 2023.3.

Comment: @Slaw I tried it on JavaFX 21.0.1 and nothing changed.

Comment: @Slaw Does it work on your platform?

Comment: Yes. Executing `./mvnw compile javafx:run` worked just fine (at least after fixing the `<mainClass>` configuration in your POM).

Comment: @Slaw Even after downloading Bellsoft's Liberica, which comes with JavaFX, I continued to receive the same issue. It must have something to do with having an AMD CPU. I'm not sure...

Comment: Maybe. I have an Intel, but what runs on Intel _should_ run on AMD as well. And JavaFX, when you're using the Maven artifacts, seems to be extracting the `gstreamer-lite.dll` library correctly. It may be your computer is missing some library that GStreamer depends on, but I don't know what that could be.

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: @jewelsea Windows 11 Home N with AMD Ryzen 5 7535HS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @jewelsea and @Slaw for helping me to solve the problem.

JavaFX's media module depends on the Windows Media Feature Pack *(if you are using an "N" edition of Windows)* and needs the C-written gstreamer-lite media package.

The gstreamer-lite package is supplied in the JavaFX Maven modules, or jmods, or the JavaFX SDK distribution.  gstreamer-lite will be automatically extracted to a cache directory if required when JavaFX is initialized, requiring no user intervention to install.

**The Windows Media Feature Pack needs to be manually installed.**

Make sure the media feature pack is installed by going to Settings > Applications > Optional features.

[image: Optional features]

Happy Coding!

Microsoft information on the Windows Media Feature Pack:

- [Media Feature Pack list for Windows N editions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions-c1c6fffa-d052-8338-7a79-a4bb980a700a)
- [Media Feature Pack for Windows 10/11 N (September 2022)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-11-n-september-2022-78cfeea5-c7d9-4aa8-b38f-ee4df1392009)

> Windows 10/11 N includes the same functionality as other Windows 10/11 editions, except for Windows Media Player and related technologies. Customers can restore the functionality of these technologies by installing the Media Feature Pack for N versions of Windows 10/11.