# Error in Playing .mp4 video using Java Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, media-player, mp4

I am having issues playing .mp4 video in Java Springboot. The exception I am getting is "MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!".

Here is my code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;

@Controller
public class VideoPlayer{

    @GetMapping("/playVideo")
    public String playVideo(Model model) {
        try {
            String videoFile = "src/main/resources/movies/IMG_0055.mp4"; // Replace with the actual path to your MOV file

            // Initialize JavaFX toolkit (needed for MediaPlayer)
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

            // Create a media object
            Media media = new Media(new URL("file:" + videoFile).toExternalForm());
            // Create a media player
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

            // Create a media view
            MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

            // Set up the JavaFXPanel for video playback
            JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
            fxPanel.setScene(new javafx.scene.Scene(new javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane(mediaView)));

            // Set up the JFrame
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Video Player");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(800, 600);
            frame.setContentPane(fxPanel);

            // Display the JFrame
            frame.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            model.addAttribute("error", "Error playing video: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return "video";
    }

}
```

I imported Media, Media View and Media Player. I did not import javafx.media library since it is no longer used. I instead imported javafx.scene.media.Media. Could you help me why this may be an error.

Comment: 1. Don't mix JavaFX and Swing/AWT unless you absolutely have to. 2. Spring has nothing to do with your issue.  3. Get your app to work without Spring, if it still fails provide the code here as a [mcve]. 4. Provide the full stack trace from the minimal example in the question as text, formatted as code. 5. Provide a link to media which fails for you. 6. Implement error handling as shown in the [media javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html). 6. There was never a package named `javafx.media`, that is a module.

Comment: 7. Update the question to provide info on the JavaFX version being used, JDK version and the OS version. 8. You say you are initializing the JavaFX toolkit, but you are not, you are initializing the awt toolkit. 9. The JavaFX lifecycle is documented in the [`Application`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) class or [`JFXPanel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) if you must use that.

Comment: 10. If using Window N, you need to [install Windows media components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634223/unable-to-play-audio-loading-library-gstreamer-lite-from-resource-failed/77639996#77639996).